# Delete Rows 1-150934 in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to delete rows 1-150934 from my database.

Unfortunately, the ID's in this section are not 1-150934 (as they are shuffled) so I cannot match on that.  The only thing I can go on is that I need to delete the first 150934 rows that appear in my table Listing_Summary.

Is this possible?

I have never ran a delete statement before.  I looked on here and did not find a Where statement that would match was I was trying to do.

Thanks.

Comment: rows in a database has no order, so you can not delete the first n rows

Comment: What about this?

DELETE TOP(150934)
FROM Listing_Summary

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/delete_top.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` to limit the number of rows that are deleted:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

From [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> The MySQL-specific `LIMIT row_count` clause for `DELETE` specifies the maximum number of rows to be deleted.

**Edit:** Do not use this command as-is, but you are going to want to do something similar to this:

```
DELETE FROM `Listing_Summary`
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 150934
```

You will need to update the `...` in the WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause based on your particular use-case.

Comment: Would this be the exact command?  If not, please revise as this is the first time running such statement.

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM Listing_Summary
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT 150934]

Comment: I'm not going to get baited into accidentally deleting a bunch of data from your database. This is not the "exact" command. This is the reference manual's explanation of how the DELETE command works. I have no idea what your WHERE or ORDER BY statements will be. Usually people will build a SELECT statement to query the data they want to delete then modify the SELECT command to match the DELETE syntax. You would simply be adding the LIMIT clause as well as it is not a very common operation from my experience.

Comment: Just saw you updated your comment. The square brackets stuff indicates optional portions of the statement. Looks like you might want to review MySQL syntaxes and do a couple practice DELETEs on another test database before doing something like this.

Comment: I have a backup of the database and the table if something happens.  In theory it would be easier for me to delete all data in SQL, delete the rows from the back I do not want and then import the data back into SQL but I keep having the timeout error which would take all day to fully upload.  I do not have a WHERE statement as my only goal is to delete the first 150934 records.

Comment: If you do not have a WHERE or ORDER BY then you can omit those portions of the DELETE command, but it is important to note that you cannot guarantee that the data being deleted is correct without having a WHERE or ORDER BY. The data may not come out in the same exact order every single time, even though it often does.

Comment: Good point.  Before I do this, I will review the other tables and see if I have another method of accomplishing the same goal.  Thanks for the encouragement and help.  I do appreciate it.